# Community Dynamic Fields from the Account

Tags: visualforce, community, customer-community, lightning-community, html-area-component

So we are working in our Company to build a support portal page. Our team would like to have in the site how many open and closed cases.

My ideas ran dry when I tried to ask Salesforce for help, now I am coming here to get some ideas and solutions to this problem.

So I am open to a Visualforce page, but ideally if we can make this work in HTML Editor that would be the best.

Here is what we mocked up. We will only do open/closed for the statues.
[image]

Comment: You're going to have to write custom code (Visualforce) for this. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please edit to add information

Comment: @identigral I haven't tried anything yet as I am unsure where to even start.

Comment: Start with a [VisualForce trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals).